# Add UVs back into a model

Tags: 3d, models, blender, uv-mapping

I built a 3D model in Autodesk 123d design, then exported it as an stl. When I convert it into an obj, however, there were no UVs in it.

Is there a way I can add the UVs back into the model using a program like blender?

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STL doesn't export coords so there isn't a work around. Unless the program exports directly to obj (I'm guessing it doesn't hence the workaround) or you can export the coords in another format, you're stuck having to redo the unwrap yourself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

*"STL files describe only the surface geometry of a three-dimensional object without any representation of color, texture or other common CAD model attributes"*